# Issue with Converting Full-Width Japanese Numeric Characters and Dots in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm facing an issue with converting full-width Japanese numeric characters and dots to their half-width in a JavaScript input handling function. The goal is to allow users to input numeric values with half-width characters and dots, and convert any full-width numeric value or dots to their half-width equivalents. However, there seems to be a problem in the conversion process.

Here is the js which currently used for conversion :

```js
function checkNumber(field, event) {
    const inputValue = $(field).val();
    // Check if the input is a numeric character (English or Japanese)
    const isFullWidthNumeric = /^[\d０-９.]*$/g.test(inputValue);
    const isHalfWidthNumeric = /^[0-9.]*$/g.test(inputValue);

    // Allow the backspace key (keyCode 8) and delete key (keyCode 46)
    if (event.which !== 8 && event.which !== 46 && !(isFullWidthNumeric || isHalfWidthNumeric)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}

function convertToHalfWidth(input) {
    // Define a mapping of full-width to half-width numeric characters
      const fullWidth = '０１２３４５６７８９．'; 
        const halfWidth = '0123456789.';

    // Use the replace function to perform the conversion
    let result = input;
    for (let i = 0; i < fullWidth.length; i++) {
        const regex = new RegExp(fullWidth[i], 'g');
        result = result.replace(regex, halfWidth[i]);
    }

    return result;
}

// Call this function in the on input event of your input field
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", handleInput);
function handleInput(event) {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    console.log("Input Value:", inputValue);
    // Remove non-numeric characters
    const numericValue = inputValue.replace(/[^0-9０-９.]/g, '');
    console.log("Value Value:", numericValue);
    // Convert to half-width
    const convertedValue = convertToHalfWidth(numericValue);
    console.log("convertedValue Value:", convertedValue);
    // Update the input field value only if it has changed
    if (event.target.value !== convertedValue) {
        event.target.value = convertedValue;
    }
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Input examples: **`123４５６．７８９`** should be converted to **`123456.789`**.                                                                   if anyone have idea please help.                                                                                                                                   Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"there seems to be a problem in the conversion process."*: what is the problem? For the example at the bottom, I get the desired result with your code... I edited your question and turned the code into a runnable snippet. If I paste the example input, I get the desired output. Please clarify what the problem is.

Comment: when i am trying to input . in full width char it is not allowing me to input

Comment: That seems to be a problem with your input widget, not with the code you have provided. Please edit your question to make the problem reproducible in the snippet.

Comment: Input Value: １２３．
Value Value: １２３
convertedValue Value: 123

Comment: currently getting output like this

Comment: it is removing full width . instead of converting it to half width.

Comment: Again, I cannot reproduce that. See the snippet in your question and run it. It does not have that effect when I run it. Please clarify.

Comment: tried to input like this :１２３．１３４

Answer (score 0):

The problem would be in your regex `/[^0-9０-９.]/g` which doesn't handle the FULLWIDTH FULL STOP `．` character.

But you are making things a lot more complicated than necessary. For a few years now, `String` has a [normalize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) method which allows you get the Unicode Normalization Form of the passed characters.

```js
// Call this function in the on input event of your input field
document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("input", handleInput);
function handleInput(event) {
    const inputValue = event.target.value;
    const normalizedValue = inputValue.normalize("NFKC")
    // Now we get only simple characters, the regex is much simpler
    const convertedValue = normalizedValue.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
    console.log("convertedValue Value:", convertedValue);
    // Update the input field value only if it has changed
    if (event.target.value !== convertedValue) {
        event.target.value = convertedValue;
    }
}
```

```html
<input>
```

Note that I removed the `checkNumber` function because it wasn't used.

Comment: i have applied this in js and i am using this function on multiple input field sometime it is working fine but sometime not.

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. When is it not working?

Comment: on some position when i input . it is properly inputting but on some position it is not inputting.

Comment: You do realize we're not in the same room as you and we don't see neither your monitor nor your keyboard, right?

Comment: It seems like experiencing inconsistency in the input behavior, particularly with the decimal point, where sometimes it's accepted and sometimes not, especially when entered in succession like "1.2345.3456.3456634.21112.4512.456.12456".

Comment: What IME are you using? On which OS?

Comment: IME -> Japanese IME ,OS -> Windows

Comment: ... Then I can't help. On a mac myself with Full-Width Romaji IDE and it works just fine... Try to add logs here and there to see what happens when you face the issue, e.g. check what was the original input, and if `event.isComposing` is true somehow?